Will a circuit oscillate at all its resonance modes or only the most dominant one?
Will a circuit oscillate at all its resonance modes or only the most dominant one?
Consider an amplifier with a feedback loop that meets the Barkhausen criteria at multiple frequencies.  Will it oscillate at all of them or just the one with the highest gain?
Argument for all: That's why we have phase noise if the Q is low.
Argument for dominant: All crystals have multiple modes.  Some circuits block some modes, but other circuits don't - and yet they seem to oscillate at only the dominant.
Bakground: I now understand why this circuit oscillates (How can this Clapp JFET oscillate when its gate is tied to ground at the resonance frequency?), but can't figure out why it only oscillates at one frequency.  This led to a broader inquiry about any oscillator with multiple Barkhausen satisfying frequencies, which I can't find anywhere.

In your linked question, a crystal isn't involved so how is it relevant? And anyway, they don't oscillate at their resonant frequency but, to one side of their resonant frequency.

@Andyaka That is true for Pierce oscillators where the crystal needs load caps as the inductive region is used, but does it also apply to crystals intended for series resonance (the circuit with two inverters and no load caps)?

I was referring to the OP's earlier question not operating at resonant frequency. Maybe link a diagram for the two inverter oscillator @Justme

@Andyaka It's the same diagrams on every crystal appnote describing "series" and "parallel" crystal resonances, here for example : https://forum.digikey.com/t/resonant-crystals-series-vs-parallel/421

It really depends on the system.  If it is linear, it can oscillate at all resonances (think parallel LC filters).  If it is nonlinear it might resonant at one or a few modes (e.g. a narrow linewidth DFB laser) or at a very large number of modes (e.g. a mode locked femtosecond laser).

@Justme the first line of the app note told me I was in for a bad read so I gave up. They got it wrong about what the xtal pi filter circuit does when they called it "parallel" resonance. It's never parallel resonance but somewhere between series and anti-resonance but closer to series resonance. The series resonant circuit I've never analysed but does feed a virtual GND and so has quite a significant loading and operating current. However, I'm unsure how the 2nd inverter gets biased.

Ultimately, an oscillator is a nonlinear dynamical system; which also puts it in the class of chaotic systems.
Well-enough behaved oscillators typically exhibit a negative-resistance characteristic for small signals, and a limiting characteristic for large signals.  This may involve intra-cycle effects like clipping or slew rate limiting, or inter-cycle or time-dependent effects like gain modulation (e.g. the classic lightbulb limiter of Hewlett and Packard fame).
In the negative-resistance regime, multiple frequencies can be excited by thermal noise or other sources; if they happen to grow at the same rate, multiple frequencies can begin activating the limiting effects simultaneously.  Which frequencies win out, depends which get there first, and how the limiting effect plays out.  It will generally be the case that one comes to dominate, as the others get diluted by intermodulation.
For a crystal oscillator, it's usually sufficient that the dominant mode is stronger than others, and it starts up naturally.  For overtone crystals, an LC network is usually required to reduce the fundamental in favor of another range.
Limiting doesn't need to occur by the amplifier itself.  A negative resistance topology can be wired to a multi-resonant network with limiters on individual resonators, so that they aren't competing within the amplifier's range but limit themselves as such.  Such a mechanism was employed for early DTMF phones, back in the 1960s when transistors were still quite expensive devices:

Western Electric 2500D phone wiring diagram, courtesy Telephone Collectors International Library. Downloaded from: https://www.telephonecollectors.info/index.php/browse/wiring-diagrams/western-electric/2500-series/2215-2500-series-telephones-2500d/file
They don't give component values or inductor couplings unfortunately, but as a rough skeleton, you can see some of what's going on here.  Most importantly, notice the LC resonators on the right side, consisting of a limiting element (a TVS-like symbol is used, but it may actually be a varistor), a capacitor, and some combination of inductors wired in series or parallel (or maybe they're windings of a coupled inductor, I don't know), selected by pressing the key matrix.  Notice the four switches for rows, and three for columns (optionally four for party-line systems and such).
